# rails 4.2 assets precompilation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, web-deployment

i'm testing the deployment af RoR 4.2.x app...

when i execute it in development all runs fine, 
if i simulate deployment on a vm to prepare final deployment phase, 
i receive an error during asset precompilation....

the deployment env is ubuntu 14.04 lts server using rvm, passenger and Apache as web server..

after all needed library updates (as prerequisites) i've done a checkout of the repo to the working dir onto web server, 
then correctly executed 'bundle update' inside the working dir to correctly populate the gemset...

during this phase no errors are returned from the server console, all seems to run fine...

if i run 'gem list' all needed gems results present

now, precompiling assets using the command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

the operation aborts after few seconds with this error:

```
rake aborted!
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery-ui' with type 'application/javascript'
/home/rails-usr/www_v2/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:10
/home/rails-usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@Best-i-gest_v2/gems/sprockets-3.6.2/lib/sprockets/resolve.rb:64:in `resolve!'
/home/rails-usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@Best-i-gest_v2/gems/sprockets-3.6.2/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:399:in `resolve'
/home/rails-usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@Best-i-gest_v2/gems/sprockets-3.6.2/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:207:in `process_require_directive'
.....
```

going to add some more info to my question...

here is my app 'Gemfile'

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.5'

gem 'mysql2', '0.3.17'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', :require => 'bcrypt'
gem 'declarative_authorization', :git => 'git://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization'
gem 'ruby_parser'
gem 'jQuery-Validation-Engine-rails'
gem 'prawn', '1.3.0'
gem 'prawn-table', '0.2.1'

# gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'

  gem "therubyracer"
  gem "less-rails", :git => 'git://github.com/metaskills/less-rails', :ref => '539f28d'

  gem 'jquery-datatables-rails' , :git => 'git://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
end

gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/coppolaf/tb3-rails4.git'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'nokogiri'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', '~> 0.8.3', :require => false
end
```

this is 'application.js' file:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
// Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll automatically
// be included in the compiled file accessible from http://example.com/assets/application.js
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require jquery.validationEngine
//= require_tree .
....
```

this is 'application.css' file:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require_self
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require dataTables/src/demo_table_jui
 *= bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less
 *= require validationEngine.jquery
 *= require_tree .
 */
....
```

pls note all jquery modules runs fine in development, the requested module seems to be present inside gemset....

waiting your suggestions,

regards, 
francesco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Wishalizer suggestions, i've finally solved this issue...

the error is related to the Gemfile structure.... i've modified it as follows......

file: 'Gemfile'

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.5'

gem 'mysql2', '0.3.17'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', :require => 'bcrypt'
gem 'declarative_authorization', :git => 'git://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization'
gem 'ruby_parser'
gem 'jQuery-Validation-Engine-rails'
gem 'prawn', '1.3.0'
gem 'prawn-table', '0.2.1'

# gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'

  gem "therubyracer"
  gem "less-rails", :git => 'git://github.com/metaskills/less-rails', :ref => '539f28d'

end

gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/coppolaf/tb3-rails4.git'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails' , :git => 'git://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'nokogiri'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', '~> 0.8.3', :require => false
end
```

moving the references to jquery-ui-rails and jquery-datatables-rails outside the assets section... 
enables the assets precompilation task to complete without errors!!

hoping this to be helpful....

bye
francesco

Comment: @Wishalizer - i'm going to thank you again for your help... if my answer seems to you "incorrect" on any manner, pls feel free to move the solution you've suggested me inside your answer section, complete it with all appropriate annotations, then let me know when you've done... so i may remove my 'solution'... i've no interest at all to create any kind of trouble, only looking to help  other people with similar issue to easily locate a solution that made me loose a lot of time!!! - regards - francesco

Comment: (PS: i just solved anther issue related to this previous one... assets precompilation was failing for 'twitter-bootstrap-rails' gem too, this secondary issue has started after the modifications we've discussed here... to solve i've move out of assets section the  'less-rails' gem also!

Answer (score 0):

From the sprockets error you posted, I expect this line is missing from your `application.js`

```
//= require jquery-ui
```

[Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

**Added**

Your additional information is helpful. **Your application.css should not include jquery-ui**, which is not css and will throw a sprockets error consistent with what you're seeing. I would reduce your application.css to include to only css type assets.

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less
 *= any other css, scss, etc
 *= require_self
  */
```

Let me know how this goes.

---

**Suggested test**

I just noticed that there is a diff between dev and prod. in your jquery-ui setup. This is an important test, since it is an asset load problem you're seeing. This what you have:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'

  gem "therubyracer"
  gem "less-rails", :git => 'git://github.com/metaskills/less-rails', :ref => '539f28d'

  gem 'jquery-datatables-rails' , :git => 'git://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
end
```

**Try moving the gem outside the assets group** in the Gemfile, like below and `$bundle install` and test:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

Let me know what happens

Comment: first of all... thanks for your time!!! i'm going to add to my question some info 've missed before (Gemfile + application.js header + application.css header)

Comment: You're quite welcome. Added another section to the answer.

Comment: @coppola_f Did this help?

Comment: just finished testing this solution.... i've modified application.js as you suggested, removed jquery-ui references from application.css file.... started assets precompilation.... no solution... the massage is still the same, only difference, it now refers to different library 'jquery_ui'.... pls note: jquery-ui-rails gem is at version 5.0.5, i've followed these instruction to make my old configuration: [link] (https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails)

Comment: Wish I could have been more help. I use jquery in my UI but I use jquery_rails which is a general purpose jquery solution. I'm surprised no one who has used jquery-ui has offered any help with your question. As far your problem the difference in behavior in Dev vs. Prod gives you the hint that it's an assets load issue. My experience is that those can be a nightmare to track down. I would use the console and debugging statements and try to narrow down the failure. Or use jquery-rails and set up your own CSS.

Comment: Ok... i'll try again and again.... may be i'll try to implement my app using another jquery gem (like the One you've suggested....) when i'll find the solution i'll post it on this page... hoping to be helpful for others who will meet this kind of troubles!!! Many thanks again.... bye

Comment: I have an idea to try -- it's code, so I'll put it in the answer box

Comment: i've solved, your last suggestion helped me a lot!! all details inside the answer section!! many thanks again - you saved me a lot of time!